# distance of divs in array from top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the distance of divs in an array from the top of the window but am receiving the error "player.offset is not a function". Where am I going wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-player'));
        
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    let scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollTop)
    players.forEach(function(player) {
        let playerOffset = player.offset().top,
            distance      = (playerOffset - scrollTop);
        console.log(playerOffset, distance)
    })
});
```

```css
.js-player {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-player"></div>
<div class="js-player"></div>
<div class="js-player"></div>
```

Comment: Also, `playerTop` doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.offset()** is a jQuery function, see http://api.jquery.com/offset/.

You should either wrap **player** variable into jQuery and call **.offset().top** like this:

```
let playerOffset = $(player).offset().top;
```

Or use the native HTMLElement **offsetTop** value, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop

```
let playerOffset = player.offsetTop;
```

Answer (score 1):

`player` is a js Element. `offset()` is a jquery function. Therefore you need a jquery object:

```
 $(player).offset().top
```

However in the long term you should either use pure js or pure jquery, but dont mix them, that just creates confusion (like in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use offset on a DOM element, Something like this should work:

```
$('.js-player').offset().top - $('.js-player').offset().top
```